# NodeJS https POST request throws socket hang up error if any data is written

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, https, meteor

I am trying to interface with an external API and I need to POST an XML document over HTTPS.

So I am using the node https interface to try to make the request but if I try to write any data (The XML document) it throws a socket hang up. If I write nothing or an empty string to the request it completes the post just fine.

I've googled and found other people with this error but I haven't been able to fix it following the solutions others have found.

I am using Meteor, which has the HTTP package for making these types of requests. The HTTP package was also throwing this error so I dug down and implemented the post using the node 'https' package thinking it would solve the issue but I get the same error with https as well.

Here is my code:

```
var http = Npm.require("http");
var oauthSignature = Npm.require('oauth-signature');
var URL = Npm.require('url');

var content = "XML String Here";
var postDestinationUrl = "https://example.com/api/path";

var authObject = {
    oauth_consumer_key: "consumerKey",
    oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
    oauth_timestamp: (Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)).toString(10),
    oauth_nonce: Random.id(),
    oauth_version: "1.0"
};

authObject.oauth_signature = oauthSignature.generate("POST", postDestinationUrl, authObject, "shared Secret Here");
var authString = objectToQueryString(authObject);

var headers = {
    Connection: "keep-alive",
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(content),
    Authorization: authString,
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
};

var parsedUrl = URL.parse(postDestinationUrl);

var requestOptions = {
    hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
    path: parsedUrl.pathname,
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers
};


var request = https.request(requestOptions, function(response){
    var body = '';
    console.log("statusCode from https.request: ", response.statusCode);
    console.log("headers from https.request: ", response.headers);

    response.on("data", function(data){
        body += data;
    });  // end of data

    response.on("end", function(){
        console.log("body from https.request: ", body);
    }); // end of end

    response.on("error", function(){
        console.log("error in https.request response");
    }); // end of error
}); // end of request

request.write(content);
request.end();

request.on("error",function(error){
    console.log("Error in https.request: " + error.message);
    callback(error, undefined);
}); // end of error




var objectToQueryString = function(queryObject){
    var queryString = "";
    _.each(queryObject, function(value, key, list){
        queryString += key + '="' + value +'",';
    });
    return queryString.substr(0, queryString.length -1);
};
```

And the error I am seeing:

```
"stack":"Error: socket hang up
at Object.Future.wait (/Users/dsyko/.meteor/tools/f3947a4651/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
at packages/meteor/helpers.js:111
at Meteor.methods.submitAPIPost (packages/api-interface/api_server.js:412)
at packages/check/match.js:77
at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:35)
at Object.Match._failIfArgumentsAreNotAllChecked (packages/check/match.js:76)
at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1403)
at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:580
at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:35)
at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:579
 - - - - -
at createHangUpError (http.js:1472:15)
at CleartextStream.socketCloseListener (http.js:1522:23)
at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at tls.js:696:10
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)"
```

I've used [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to make the same API request and it goes through just fine so it doesn't seem to be a bad endpoint. I also switched over to posting to http and used Wireshark to inspect the headers and content of the HTTP POSTs to make sure I'm not mangling something in the request but it all looked ok there. Also when I switched over to http the XML document goes through just fine and I don't see the socket hangup (Although the endpoint responds with a re-direct to the https url so I can't just use http)

Comment: I have same experience on https. when connecting to some google services it work. not working for salesforce nor .NET. I personally think it is node.js bug/issue in the ssl implementation. I seen somewhere people suggest v0.11.xx fixed the issue.

Comment: Any work arounds? Are there any good NPM packages that implement an https post that don't use the underlying node package?

Comment: try those curl wrapper packages they should work.